# How to export Panels and Mini Panels with Features?

Tags: panels, features

I am trying to export the Panels and Mini Panels on my website with Features.

On the features drop down menu, there is an option for `"Panels: panels_renderer_pipeline"`. However, when I click on it, no checkboxes appear.

I have looked though the `"StrongArm"` option but cannot find anything related to Panels and Mini Panels.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure the panel was not already added to another feature-module. You need to add the pagemanager stuff (handlers and pages) to the feature too.

BTW the pagemanager status enabled/disabled is set via a drupal variable, so check also strongarm: If i.E. node/%node is enabled, then the variable `page_manager_node_view_disabled` is set to `FALSE`.

Comment: The page_manager_node_view_disabled variable tips is so much valuable! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In Feature, add the dependent modules as well.  If you are using views with panels then the views panes modules should be present as well. So check all the dependent modules, as well.

Enable strongarm module.
In Feature, export the following variables under Strongarm:

- "**page_manager_node_view_disabled**" for node overides
- "**page_manager_term_view_disabled**" for taxonomy overides